# Uploading large 800gb json file from remote server to elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, import, bigdata

I'm trying to upload an 800gb json file from a remote server to my local server but elasticsearch keeps getting killed. 
Im using this code to upload data

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/carrier/data/ -d@carrier.json
```

Is this because a post request cant handle 800 gb or a configuration ive missed somewhere. Ive also mapped everything appropriately as smaller files upload easily.

Comment: There isn't a specification for max request size but webservers will generally impose one, varies of course but probably well under 800gb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to index a document, elasticsearch needs to allocate this document in memory first and then buffer it in an analyzed form again. So, you typically looking at double the size of the memory for the documents that you are indexing (it's more complex than that, but 2x is a good approximation). So, unless you have 1.6tb of memory on your machine I shouldn't try to index 800gb documents. If you have several documents in this json, you need to split them into chunk and send to elasticsearch using multiple [Bulk Requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: so i ended up bringing it to the same directory and used a post command to upload data onto elasticsearch but it keeps getting killed... 
im using this command..

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/carrier/data/ -d@carrier.json

Comment: It doesn't matter which directory you put it to. It has to fit in memory. What is the format of this file?

Comment: its a .json file. I have 3tb of memeory free so it should be fine. Is there a special node configuration ive missed?

Comment: Wow, 32TB of RAM. Which computer is it? I am really curious now. Having free RAM is not enough. You need to configure java heap to use this memory. The problem is that java (GC part to be precise) doesn't really work that well with with heap sizes larger than 32G. I know some users who used elasticsearch with 64-100GB of memory with some success, but I never heard of anyone running it with 3TB of heap. If you will manage to start it with 3TB of java heap - let me know. To configure heap size see [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html).